# SQL Server: How to identify and delete duplicate XML data with specific attribute

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an XML column with some duplicate nodes (attributes) in it. I want to identify and delete them.

My XML looks like this.

```
<contact id="1">
  <lname>AA</lname>
  <fname>BB</fname>
</contact>
<contact id="2">
  <lname>CC</lname>
  <fname>DD</fname>
</contact>
**<contact id="2">
  <lname>EE</lname>
  <fname>FF</fname>
</contact>**
<contact id="3">
  <lname />
  <fname />
</contact>
```

I want to delete this node with has a duplicate attribute value of id="2".

```
<contact id="2">
  <lname>EE</lname>
  <fname>FF</fname>
</contact>
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you give a slightly more detailed explanation of the setup you're using?

Comment: I want to write a query to delete the duplicate node in the  xml  so that my final xml should look like this.                                                                     <contact id="1">
  <lname>AA</lname>
  <fname>BB</fname>
</contact>
<contact id="2">
  <lname>CC</lname>
  <fname>DD</fname>
</contact>
<contact id="3">
  <lname />
  <fname />
</contact>

Comment: As @Yahya suggested: always give us an idea of what you have tried already. While it may be tempting to have other people solve your problems, we are much more inclined to help people who have shown effort.

Comment: I achieved the first part of identifying the duplicates... I did not post it here since i thought my script may misguide you. Here is my Script.
create table #Members1 (MemberID varchar(50), XMLCount int)

INSERT INTO #Members1
(MemberID, XMLCount)
SELECT memberid
      ,C.value('@id', 'int') as [Info]
      FROM tblmembers WITH (NOLOCK)
      CROSS APPLY
     tblmembers.ContactInfo.nodes('contact') as X(C) 
     
DELETE FROM [#Members1] WHERE dbo.#Members1.XMLCount IN (1,3) 

SELECT MemberID, count(*) count FROM [#Members1]  WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY dbo.#Members1.MemberID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by decomposing your XML, distinct different Ids with `Row_Number` and then reassembling the xml.

I mean something like this:

```
Select  t.id    As '@id',
        t.fname As 'fname',
        t.lname As 'lname'
From (
    Select  x.value('@id[1]', 'varchar(30)')    As id,
            x.value('lname[1]', 'varchar(30)')  As lname,
            x.value('fname[1]', 'varchar(30)')  As fname,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By  x.value('@id[1]', 'varchar(30)') Order By x.value('@id[1]', 'varchar(30)')) As r
    from @x.nodes('/contact') as t(x)
    ) As t
Where t.r = 1
For Xml Path('contact')
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks Il-Vic, Your solution worked for my example... I will try to implement it in  my solution. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do in-place modifications via [XML Data Modification Language (XML DML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454.aspx), specifically the [delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190254.aspx) command. XML DML uses the [modify() Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx) of the XML data type, along with an XQuery expression.

It should look similar to the following:

```sql
UPDATE SchemaName.TableName
SET XmlFieldName.modify('delete {XQuery expression}');
```